# Define @property in Protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a number of  `UIViewController` subclasses and I want them to share the same property called `session` which handles a "is logged in" state.

I know that I could use a parent class but this is very explicit and so I was wondering if I could "enforce" the `session` property via a shared protocol.

I have never seen an explicit property defined in a protocol (obviously you could define the setter and getter), so is defining a property inside a protocol an advisable pattern?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `@property` can also appear in the declaration of a protocol or category.

Stated in the [official apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW18). So no problem there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using a protocol it's possible to add a property:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFoobar *baz;

@end
```

And `@synthesize baz;` in every class that adopts this protocol (or you can mark the declared property as optional using the `@optional` keyword).

Answer (score 3):

You can have properties in a protocol, provided every class that conforms to your protocol have a corresponding `@synthesize` for that property, or provide a getter and setter.

Comment: But with a class category you generally can't add instance variables to a class. Well neither does the protocol, but it means that the class will conform to the property.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a protocol? Using a category I'd have to write one for each class, with a protocol I only have to `@synthesize` the declared property.

Comment: @mAu: That's a fair question. I rewrote my answer to mention how to accomplish that using a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

In .h file:

```
 @property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel *mylabel;
```

In .m file:

```
 @synthesize mylabel = _mylabel;
```

compiler will create getter and setter for mylabel.

```
Ex -> 

-(void)setMylabe:(UILabel *) mylabel { //setter


}

-(UIlabel*)mylabel { // getter


}
```